# Elasticsearch painless script update and get in a one POST call

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am using Elasticsearch 7.4, and have a unique requirement to perform below operation in elasticsearch through painless script:-

1. Update the field through painless script
2. Get the updated value in response

#1 I can perform using painless script using below to update the counter value, but how can I get the updated value in response? I want the new value ctx._source.counter in response of the POST call I made, Is there any way?

curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:9200/myindex/_update_by_query -d "{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"match":{"field1":"1"}}]}},"script":{"source":"ctx._source.counter = ctx._source.counter + params.incrementValue","lang":"painless","params":{"incrementValue":"2"}}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is different from the [specs of the _update_by_query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-response-body). In the specs you can see the response only contains stats & status of the update, and not the document body (neither initial or final).

One way to accomplish your goal is:

1. Query document to update ie. where field1==1
2. Get initial counter value
3. Update

With this, you can get compute the updated value at your end with the method of your choice. **In any case it would be two API calls not just one**.

Comment: Yes I finally handled it in application with two calls as you mentioned, but for update I used concurrency parameter sequence and primary no, as same record could have modified by other service. So, if I get concurrency error, I re fetch and try update again.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the concurrency parameter :)